# Calculate total based on drop down criteria

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function

I am creating a budget that has different expenses on one worksheet (Expense_Overview). On another worksheet, I have a list of expenses (Expense_Detail) I am entering that are categorized based on a data validation criteria I set via a list of items. I would like for the Actual Expense column in the Expense_Overview to tally the total `Expense Category` based on the data in Expense_Detail. Eg, I want to know the total of all the `Lighting` expenses.

I want to avoid pivot tables if possible. I am not comfortable with them, and I am hoping a simple SUMIF line will accomplish this.

Here is my sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XYuo1ozmHkeAnfg00gEmr9-7c8OMCTSSUM7FNm1LOnE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi Tee, common practice is to mark an answer as best answered. Check our [help] or take the [tour]. Welcome to Web Applications !!

Answer (score 1):

Please try, in B2 of Expense_Overview:

```
=sumif(Expense_Detail!D:D,A2,Expense_Detail!C:C)
```

copied down to suit, or:

```
=ArrayFormula(sumif(Expense_Detail!D:D,A2:A,Expense_Detail!C:C))
```

You have a treat in store whenever you get around to pivot tables. They are very powerful but incredibly easy to use for all that:

Select A1:D7 in Expense_Detail, Data, Pivot table report..., for **Rows** *Add field* select `Expense Category`, for **Values** *Add field* select `Amount`.

PS Remove trailing space from A3 in Expense_Overview.

PPS If a pivot table will do the job it is normally far and away the best (and often easiest!) solution.

Comment: Wonderful. Worked perfectly. Thank you so much!!!!